# Node/Express: Knowing when a visitor has left the page

Tags: node.js, express

I have a Node.js/Express server that gets data from a remote web service when the web page is viewed.

I would like to know what the best practice is for the server to know when the visitor has left the web page. At that point I would stop the server making http requests to the remote web service.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Get the client to request the data from the server?

Comment: You can catch `focus` and `blur` events on client side to determinate that tab is active/inactive and send this information by websocket. On server side you must monitoring these events and socket-close event .

Comment: @MarkChorley what if the client internet connection failed? The browser wouldn't have that opportunity. There are many circumstances that could result in my server getting webservice data when there's no client viewing.

Comment: Why is it bothering to get data from the webservice if not in response to a request from the client? What is the point?

Comment: @MarkChorley the web service requires paid for subscription of data. The authentication / user / passwords etc is handled at the back end.

Comment: Could anyone elaborate on why they've down voted my question. I thought the question was clear and would have a encouraged solutions. If the question could be presented better then please say so and I will do it. Simply downvoting a question without saying why is unhelpful. So far @pspi has provided a possible solution that I will test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use socket.io and handle the 'disconnect' event on the server.

It's also good to keep in mind that there are multiple points of failure possible between the server and the client's browser, and not always has the client "moved away" from the web page, but perhaps the network connection has died.